# Convert Java encryption code to Apex

Tags: apex, java, encryption, crypto, platform-encryption

I would like to translate this method into java for apex.
Tried in different ways and could not :/

> ```
> public static String encodeString(String stringToEncode, String secret) throws Exception {
>     byte[] keyBytes = secret.getBytes();
>     SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA1");
>     Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
>     mac.init(signingKey);
>     byte[] rawHmac = Base64.getEncoder().encode(mac.doFinal(stringToEncode.getBytes("UTF-8")));
>     return new String(rawHmac, "UTF-8");
> }
> ```

Thank you very much

@Edit

I tried this in APEX, but it does not work.

> ```
>   public static String encodeString(String stringToEncode, String Secret){
>        Blob privateKey  = Blob.valueOf(Secret);
>        Blob urlBlob = Blob.ValueOf(stringToEncode);
>        Blob Signature = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA1', urlBlob, privateKey);
>        return EncodingUtil.base64encode(Signature);
>     }
> ```

Comment: Please post the Apex code that you have written so far and describe where are having problems with it.

Comment: Please be more specific than *"it does not work"*.

Comment: @AdrianLarson 
does not generate the same key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provide is working

JAVA result from stringToEncode : HELLO / Secret : WORLD is **yHa25HOqdV7Xn900WQrc+bFivYw=**

Running this in an anonymous window works fine.

```
String stringToEncode = 'HELLO';
String Secret = 'WORLD';

Blob privateKey  = Blob.valueOf(Secret);
Blob urlBlob = Blob.ValueOf(stringToEncode);
Blob Signature = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA1', urlBlob, privateKey);
String strResult = EncodingUtil.base64encode(Signature);
System.debug(strResult);

System.assertEquals('yHa25HOqdV7Xn900WQrc+bFivYw=', strResult);
```